# [J4]Trying to add a user to Group with addUserToGroup()

Tags: joomla-4.x, user-groups

I'm trying to use the UserHelper::addUserToGroup() to add a usergroup to a user.  This is in my component when I publish one of my records, I want the owning user of that record to be added to a specific usergroup.  So in my model I have:

```
public function publish($id, $state)
{
    $app = Factory::getApplication();
    $params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_mycomponent');
    $joinCat = $params->get('join_cat', 0);
    $myGroup = $params->get('my_group', 0);

    $table = $this->getTable();
    $table->load($id);
    $table->state = $state;

    if ($table->catid == $joinCat) {
        if ($state == 1) {
            $addedOK = UserHelper::addUserToGroup($table->user_id, $myGroup);
        } else {
            $removedOK = UserHelper::removeUserFromGroup($table->user_id, $myGroup);
        }
    }

    return $table->store();

}
```

Neither the addUserToGroup or removeUserFromGroup work as I expected.  What am I missing?  All assistance gratefully received.

Comment: If the commands are not working as expected, what are they doing? Is there any messages, are they not running at all or is there other results coming back?

Comment: I get nothing back to indicate an error, it all appears to have worked but when I check the data, the group is not added/removed from the map.  As a work around I processed the data outside the UserHelper but of course the helper is suppose to do exactly what I want.  I need to review the core code but alas been distracted onto other things.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the $state variable in reverse.

```
$table->state = $state;

if ($table->catid == $joinCat) {
    if ($state == 1) {
```

I think it should be

```
$state = $table->state;
```

Comment: Hi Irata, thanks for reviewing but the state of my record (which has nothing to do with the user record or user_group_map records) is irrelevant to my question.